# Можно ли по пунктуации однозначно вычислить смысл фразы из закона

Tags: пунктуация

В законе сказано:
-  членами одной семьи являются супруги и их несовершеннолетние дети независимо от места их жительства, лица, объединенные признаками родства или свойства, совместно проживающие в жилом помещении, а также иные лица, вселенные в жилое помещение в качестве членов семьи в установленном порядке либо на основании решения суда.

Чиновники толкуют фразу «совместно проживающие в жилом помещении» не как причастный оборот, а как обособленное, независимое обстоятельство, не связанное с лицами, объединенными признаками родства. То есть все, посторонние друг другу люди, признаются членами одной семьи.

Вопрос. Можно ли на основе правил русского языка однозначно доказать, что часть предложения «совместно проживающие в жилом помещении» бесспорно привязана к «лицам, объединенным признаками родства или свойства»?

Comment: А нельзя ли почетче? Потому что вы путаете обстоятельство с определением, да и вообще, что такое "независимое обстоятельство"... Желательно конкретный пример привести, который, с вашей точки зрения, чиновники неправильно толкуют.

Comment:    Излагаю почётче, с конкретным примером. Я собственник половины комнаты в коммуналке. Соседи-содольщики посторонние мне лица и никогда не были мне родственниками. Метраж всех их жилых площадей по РФ, не позволяет им встать на жил учёт. А мой метраж позволяет. Чиновники, толкуя фразу «совместно проживающие в жилом помещении» как не привязанную к «лицам, объединенным признаками родства или свойства», причисляют соседей, вместе с их метражом, к моей семье. Получается, что у меня (у моей «семьи») избыток метража. Поэтому, мне отказано в улучшении жил. условий.

Comment: Ну, это к юристам, а не сюда. Вообще-то фраза совершенно однозначная и не допускает двоякого толкования. Но, повторяю, это должны установить юристы, а никакая там не Грамота.ру. Вопрос, на мой взгляд, выеденного яйца не стоит.

Comment: @Конст, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Грамматика предложения явно подразумевает, что одну семью составляют три группы лиц: 1) супруги и несовешеннолетние дети; 2) лица, объединенные призаками родства или свойства, совместно проживающие в одном помещении; 3) другие лица, вселенные в качестве членов семьи. Но правильная грамматическая стилистика для чиновника не аргумент.

Группу 2 во избежание разночтения можно бы обозначить как "лица, объединенные признаками родства ИЛИ свойства и совместно проживающие в одном помещении". Но делать это необязательно, так как искусственное разделение группы 2 на две части – это даже  НЕ ГРАММАТИЧЕСКАЯ, А ЛОГИЧЕСКАЯ ОШИБКА.

Действительно,  рассмотрим ОТДЕЛЬНО первую часть группы 2  -  "лица, объединенные призаками родства или свойства".   Тогда получается, что  к одной семье нужно отнести всех родственников (бабушек, дедушек, дядей, тетей и т.д.) во всех городах и странах?

Нет, здесь для "лиц, объединенных признаками родства или свойства" обязательно требуется совместное проживание, поэтому делить группу 2 на части нельзя, она составляет единое целое  -  это СОВМЕСТНО ПРОЖИВАЮЩИЕ РОДСТВЕННИКИ.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но он тоже не однозначен. Явно не значит точно. Думаю, грамматика не запрещает подразумевать в предложении, что одну семью составляют четыре группы лиц: 1) супруги и несовешеннолетние дети; 2) лица, объединенные признаками родства или свойства; 3) совместно проживающие в одном помещении; 4) другие лица, вселенные в качестве членов семьи.  
Отделение группы 2 от группы 3 тоже может не быть логической ошибкой. Такой могла быть задумка законодателя. Этот закон только для жителей одного города. Поэтому собирать всех родственников во всех городах и странах не надо.

Comment: Тогда Вам только к юристу, русский язык здесь не поможет, это совершенно очевидно. (Можете  для начала в Интернете задать бесплатный вопрос). Вообще говоря, ситуация странная, так как обычно люди для постановки на учет стараются увеличить свою семью, а чиновники им в этом препятствуют. Например, взрослые дети, проживающие отдельно от родителей, не входят в семью. Да и  ЖК конкретного города должен согласовываться с ЖК РФ.

Comment: Юридическая сторона проблемы, это отдельная тема, которой я параллельно занимаюсь.  На этом сайте я хочу выяснить истину чисто с грамматической точки зрения. Вопрос на др. сайтах я уже задал. Ответа пока нет и не факт, что он будет достаточным. Ссылки данные мне на этом сайте слишком общие, требуют много времени для поиска истины, а времени у меня нет. В грамматике я дилетант.

Answer (score 0):

"Как трактуют чиновники" здесь не аргумент. Если чиновники что-то там начали "трактовать", окончательное решение может принять только суд (он назначит при необходимости лингвистическую экспертизу).

Comment: Поэтому, и для быстрого решения дела, я ищу для суда ссылку на правило русского языка.

Comment: Вы смеётесь? какая может быть для суда "ссылка"? "Ссылка" - это ваше мнение. Решение будет приниматься на основании __авторитетного__ экспертного заключения.

Comment: Наоборот, доказательная ссылка на правило русского языка, по существу спора, это не моё мнение. С ней будет шанс не загружать дело экспертизой и решить его быстро.

Comment: "Доказательная ссылка" - это ссылка на "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации 1956-го года" (которую сумеет понять судья). Или ссылка на "Русскую грамматику-1980". Всё остальное - мнения (показания) свидетелей. В суде будет учитываться только свидетельство эксперта, назначенного судом.

Comment: @Конст,не факт, что судья, сможет правильно растолковать правило. Да и не в его это в праве, на мой взгляд, решать такие вопроса без соответствующих специалистов.

Answer (score 0):

Хоть поезд ушел, но как человек, которому по воле судьбы выпало разбираться с подобными формулировками в чисто практических целях, дополню.

Во-первых, для чиновников никакое мнение не будет значимым, если оно противоречит их чиновничьему пониманию, тем более - их интересам.

Во-вторых, грамота и грамма не специалисты в подобных вопросах. Не тот случай. Лингвистическую экспертизу подобного рода делают лингвисты-эксперты, люди поднатаскавшиеся именно на судебных решениях. 
ГЛЭДиС, например ( www.rusexpert.ru ), могу другие посмотреть. Их заключение действительно щначмсо и для суда и для чиновников.

И третье. Вне разговоров о компетенции экспертиз, полностью согласна с Верой. Из самого текста документа понято, что там идет уточняющий оборот, если бы было иное, т.е. "совместно проживающие" было бы самодостаточным фактом для признания членом семьи, то это условие дублировалось бы полностью упоминанием "иных лиц, вселенных на основании...". При упомянутом чиновничьем прочтении получается, что все уточняющие детали излишни. Все живущие (юридически) совместно - все члены одной семьи. Зачем тогда на четыре строчки разводить?

> Можно ли на основе правил русского языка однозначно доказать,

Нет. Только на основании правил РЯ нельзя. Надо ещё включать логику и понимание стилистики (это не суть "правила РЯ"), а они у чиновников и простых смертных сильно отличаются.

Answer (score -1):

Если чиновников не смущает, что в их трактовке "членами семьи являются" случайные соседи по общему гостиничному номеру или комнате в общежитии, то через грамматику их убедит только заверенное экспертное заключение - или они грамматическими терминами эту идею аргументируют?

При всех недостатках фразы (её можно было улучшить разделением перечисляемых сложных элементов - вплоть до их нумерации), здесь достаточно оснований относить "проживающих" только к упомянутым перед этим  "лицам" с их свойствами: перед оборотом нет "своих" лиц. При их трактовке придётся из перечисляемого определить в "члены семьи" нечто не являющееся даже существительным.

"Членами одной семьи являются... совместно проживающие в жилом помещении".

Здесь причастие "проживающие" - совсем не то, что "понятые", "поверенные" или хотя бы "больные", которые могли бы обозначать физических лиц и иметь самостоятельный юридический смысл. Поэтому читающим нужно относить оборот с "проживающими" к ранее упомянутым и уже охарактеризованным (родством или свойством) "лицам". Если их это не убедит, дальше уговаривать их придётся тем, что перечисляются здесь ровно три однородных сущности, группы лиц (к которым отнесены остальные "эпитеты"):

- супруги с детьми,
- лица,
- иные лица.

Если читающие не согласятся, что нехорошо перечислять существительные вперемежку с причастиями, можно будет и дальше поискать - сначала нужно посмотреть, как отреагируют :) .

Comment: Нет, грамматическими терминами чиновники своё толкование не аргументируют. Просто толкуют как им удобнее, по праву сильного. И, что членами семьи являются случайные соседи, их не смущает, так как закон позволяет такое соседство.   
А почему "проживающие" это причастие. Есть ли какая-то ссылка на правила. Я не спец в правилах русского языка, но мне кажется, что эти правила не запрещают вставить в предложение фразу «совместно проживающие в жилом помещении» не как причастный оборот, а как обособленное, независимое обстоятельство?

Comment: Также, думаю для чиновников не будет  доказательством против них, что перечисляются три однородных сущности, группы лиц. При всей их однородности, думаю нет запрета рассматривать каждую из этих групп, включая «совместно проживающих в жилом помещении», как обособленную, независимую часть сложного предложения.   
Насчёт того, что «нехорошо перечислять существительные вперемежку с причастиями» тоже не убедит чиновников. Нехорошо не значит запрещено. Нужны однозначные аргументы, со ссылками, если такие ссылки существуют.

Comment: @Конст, дело не в том, что хорошо, а что плохо со стилистической точки зрения. Причастный оборот  может находиться или после определяемого слова (письмо, полученное от автора), или перед ним (полученное от автора письмо).[
Справочник по правописанию и стилистике
Причастные обороты
](http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/)

Comment: stopkran (в личном ответе мне), считает, что "Проживающие" - в данном контексте существительное. А тех кто с этим не согласен, считает, мягко говоря, двоечниками.

Answer (score -1):

Согласен с Александром! Обратитесь в специальную лингвистическую экспертную комиссию. Обращаться надо в престижную комиссию. Можно, на худой конец, обратиться в Грамоту.ру и Грамма.ру. Все-таки,от их мнения многое зависит. Наши ответы не примут за основание.

Comment: Экспертная комиссия это громоздко. Есть более простое решение. Дать суду ссылку на какое-то правило русского языка, что чиновники не правы, плюс доказательство, что любой орган власти обязан толковать любые сомнения в любых законах строго в пользу прав человека. Поэтому я ищу такую ссылку.

Comment: Конст, я же привел ссылку. См. выше.

Comment: Конст, слово "проживающие" не может здесь быть суб-ным существительным. Оно является зависимым от слова "лица" (лица - какие? - объединенные... и проживающие...). В доказательство своих слов, я задал вопрос как Грамме.ру, так и Грамоте.ру. Поступил ответ от **Граммы.ру**. >Вот что они пишут: "В приведенном Вами примере слово "проживающие" является причастием, не субстантивированным (лица - какие? - объединенные... и проживающие...). При этом сочетание "совместно проживающие в жилом помещении" является причастным оборотом и одновременно обособленным определением".

Comment: >Можно, на худой конец, обратиться в Грамоту.ру и Грамма.ру. Все-таки,от их мнения многое зависит.   --- ничего от их мнения не зависит, не обольщайтесь.

Comment: Ну а от вашего с нами мнения не зависит точно.

Comment: А от Грамоты.ру и от Граммы.ру.зависит многое.